# How to Validate A Smart Contract Twice?

Tags: validator, smart-contract, validation, mkvalidator

I have a smart contract I want to validate at a certain date. Exacute its logic and then revalidate on a second date. The trick is I only want it to be signed once. How do I do this?

can I just add and or statement in the validator?